# Exclude items following a condition with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of items similar to this:

```
{
  user: "ObjectId(...)"
  type: "foo",
  subType: "foo_bar",
  state: "active",
  accounts: [ObjectId(...)]
}
```

I need to create a MongoDB query (I'm not very familiar with it) that exclude all `subtype: "foo_bar"` if the `state: "active"`.

Looking at the docs I'm trying to use `$not` but I do receive error: `unknown top level operator: $not`

Trying many different queries that would be unnecessary to report here because are all containing errors...

These is the base query that is working fine and I need to attach the new condition:

```
db.items.find({ $or: [{ user: myUser._id }, { accounts: { $in: myAccountsVariable } }], state: { $ne: "closed" } })
```

Can someone help me achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert your criteria and use `$or` with `$ne`:

```
db.collection.find({ $or: [ { state: { $ne: "active" } }, { subType: { $ne: "foo_bar" } } ] })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XhW7ci1v0Cu)

Just add this to your existing query using `$and` operator

```
db.collection.find({ $and: [ 
    { $or: [ { state: { $ne: "active" } }, { subType: { $ne: "foo_bar" } } ] },
    { $or: [{ user: myUser._id }, { accounts: { $in: myAccountsVariable } }], state: { $ne: "closed" } }
    ] })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `db.items.find({"$or": [{state: "active", subType: {"$ne": "foo_bar"}}, {state: {"$ne": "active"}}]})`

This should return every item that's either active (but not foo_bar) or not active (any subtype)

**EDIT:**

Adding it to your base query should be something like

```
db.items.find(
    {   "$and": [
            { $or: [{ user: myUser._id }, { accounts: { $in: myAccountsVariable } }], state: { $ne: "closed" } },
            {"$or": [{state: "active", subType: {"$ne": "foo_bar"}}, {state: {"$ne": "active"}}]}
        ]
    }
)
```